# javascript extending prebuilt prototypes performance

Tags: javascript, compilation, prototype

Many people argue that extending the prebuilt prototypes such as for String, Array or Object is bad practice.

However, others say that it also has terrible performance hits - which makes sense since I presume caching methods in some sort hash table is now invalidated (since you could have changed that method).

What I want to know is that if you all of your prototype extending of native types once at the beginning of execution, and before any objects containing this prototype in their prototype chain are used, will this still have performance problems?

The reason I ask is because I'm working on a system which compiles to javascript. I don't care about what is bad practice in javascript, but I definitely care about performance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Jonas say's, performance is most likely not going to be an issue.

Extending the prototype is in fact how a lot of pollyfills work.

But the question you have to ask, do you plan on using any third party libs, or are you planning on making this into a library for others to use.  If so, avoid the overriding built in prototype's as it could break a lots of things..

If this is only ever going to be used internally, with your control I can't see there be any problems, as long as you don't do something silly to the built in's of course.

For extra safety, I would also think about prefixing all your methods with something unlikely to become part of the specifications.. eg.. `String.prototype.myCaptializer`,  I very much doubt this will ever become part of the spec..

Comment: How do you know performance won't be an issue? I could very easily see a system which has native inbuilt methods for say, indexOf. But if you edit the prototype of the array type, this system might fallback to always checking that the indexOf method exists in the Array prototype.

Comment: The methods will have weird number names such as "123_method_toString" or a short string such as "3"

Comment: `How do you know performance won't be an issue?`  Because I said -> `avoid the overriding built in prototype's`  overriding `indexOf` is certainly not a good idea if performance was key.

Comment: `123_method_toString`  That's not a valid method name, So you wouldn't be able to use `dot notation` on them. `my123_method_toString`  & `my3` or some sort of prefix would be better.

Comment: sorry it's method_name_{random number}. Anyway, could you explain why overriding the inbuilt prototypes in built methods will have a performance hit? Does you have hard evidence for this claim?

Comment: `Does you have hard evidence for this claim?`,  No, but there is nothing stopping you trying it out for yourself.  If your able to make an indexOf that's faster than the native version, people on SO will be interested.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll look into this. I think I'm going to try and make method lookup using the name or some kind of unique identifier of the prototype now.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that performance is the real problem. The real problem is:

```
  Object.prototype.toString = () => "whoops";

  console.log({} + ", whats going on here?!");
```

Comment: right but for my uses I'm compiling to javascript so I don't mind about totally unexpected behaviour. All I care about is the contract between my Linq Expression tree and the compiled javascript is satisfied.